# Function app posting a message to a Teams channel via Graph API - Unauthorised

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm attempting to [post a message to a Teams Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) from an Azure Function via Microsoft Graph.

I have followed the steps of registering an app in Azure AD, giving that app API permissions (`Group.ReadWrite.All`), requesting a token so my app can call Graph as a User then calling the API with that bearer token.

So far this works for retrieving messages from the Teams Channel, and the call returns all the messages from the channel as expected. But when I try to `POST` a new message, I receive an `Unauthorised` response. I think I picked the correct API permissions and had consent granted on those permissions so I can't see what I've missed or messed up.

Here are some details of my AAD token request:

- API (POST): `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/token`
- RestSharp Parameters:

  - Resource: `https://graph.microsoft.com`
  - Scope: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`
  - Client Id: {GUID of App ID}
  - Client Secret {Secret from App registration}
  - Username: (My delegated users email address)
  - Password: (My delegated users password)

And here's the token returned

```
{
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "scope":"Chat.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All TeamsActivity.Send User.Read",
  "expires_in":"3599",
  "ext_expires_in":"3599",
  "expires_on":"1581602086",
  "not_before":"1581598186",
  "resource":"https://graph.microsoft.com",
  "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6Ilp6REVFN..."
}
```

I then make the call to the Graph endpoint `/beta/teams/{Team ID}/channels/{Channel ID}/messages` with the bearer token header. I then try to `POST` a message by adding this body to the message (RestSharp):

```cs
graphRequest.AddParameter(
  "application/json", 
  "{\"body\": {\"content\": \"Hello World\"}}", 
  ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

And this is the response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "487ce496-09dd-4385-98ba-f7c1f561b996",
      "date": "2020-02-13T13:27:32"
    }
  }
```

Here is the decoded token

```
{
  "iat": 1581600138,
  "nbf": 1581600138,
  "exp": 1581604038,
  "acct": 0,
  "acr": "1",
  "aio": "{removed}",
  "amr": ["pwd"],
  "app_displayname": "{removed}",
  "appid": "{removed}",
  "appidacr": "1",
  "family_name": "test",
  "given_name": "AM",
  "ipaddr": "{removed}",
  "name": "AM Test",
  "oid": "{removed}",
  "platf": "14",
  "puid": "10032000842ED84F",
  "scp": "Chat.ReadWrite Group.ReadWrite.All TeamsActivity.Send User.Read",
  "sub": "{removed}",
  "tid": "{removed}",
  "unique_name": "{removed}.onmicrosoft.com",
  "upn": "{removed}.onmicrosoft.com",
  "uti": "{removed}",
  "ver": "1.0",
  "xms_tcdt": 1307525692
}
```

Comment: Did you decode your token on [`jwt.io`](https://jwt.io/) to make sure your token has valid permission. I doubt your is correct because your token request is seems confusing

Comment: Hi Thanks for responsing so quickly, I've removed the GUID and addresses but here is the token decoded...

Comment: Does it contain permission you required?

Comment: My apologies I hit the character limit on the comment box so I've added it to the main post.It appears to contain Group.ReadWrite.All which is the permission needed for this endpoint. i should mention this endpoint is in Beta

Comment: Are you using `grant_type:password`? and its also  confusing `Resource: https://graph.microsoft.com`
`Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` you should either use one.

Comment: Yes, i didnt have that in the question but the granttype param is 'password'... I think the scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default retreives all delegated permissions for this application and is replaced by group.readwrite.all etc, but the resource is the API web url. Is this correct?

Comment: So if your `grant_type` equals `password` and `Scope` equals `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` then your request endpoint should be `https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: Did you get my point? Is the unauthorized problem resolved now?

Comment: Is this user a member of this Team/Channel?

Comment: Hi @andymoore Have you solved this problem ? I met similar problem with yours' when I request another graph api in the past. I access the token correctly and I think everything is ok(include permission...), but the request always fail. At last I use another account and do the same configuration(access token, permission...) and then it success. So could you please switch another account and try again.

Comment: Apologies for the delay I was away for a long weekend. The grant type was password but I have been using the Tenant GUID rather than URL in my endpoint. I can confirm the user has access to the team but this is a test user that was created so i need to check with my admin id the test user has sufficient permissions to write to teams. I may also try with my own account but i would need to take 2 factor authentication off my account first. I will post again later, thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @andymoore, have you managed to sort this out?